# Не принимаются параметры jQuery.load() в PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Есть обработчик:

```
$(document).delegate('#fakeButton', 'click', function() {
    var url = 'index.php?route=checkout/guest/freetimes';
    $('#timeselect').load(url, {'date': $('#input-payment-orderdate').val()});
});
```

и функция в php:

```
function freetimes() {
$myCurl = curl_init(); 
$date = $_POST('date');

curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:56987/api/orders/freetimes?date=".$date, 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    )); 
$response = curl_exec($myCurl); 
curl_close($myCurl); 

$times = array();
$times[] = split("/", str_replace("\"","",$response));

$rez = '';

$max = sizeof($times[0]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    list($value, $start, $end) = split('-', $times[0][$i]);
    $rez = $rez.'<option value="'.$value.'">'.$start.'-'.$end.'</option>';
}

echo $rez;
}
```

Функция php полностью рабочая и с $date = date("Y-n-j") работает замечательно, но при попытке принять параметры методом POST вылетает

Не знаю как исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

> It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success)
>
> [ примерно соответствует $.get(url, data, success) ]

То есть в `load` запрос GET,  а не POST.  Или измените код php на

```
$date = $_GET['date']; (а то и $_REQUEST['date'])
```

или используйте

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST", 
  url: "index.php?route=checkout/guest/freetimes",
  data: { 'date': $('#input-payment-orderdate').val() },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    $('#timeselect').html(data);
  }
});
```